# Omit custom post type from wp-sitemap.xml based on meta key using wp_sitemaps_posts_query_args

Tags: php, functions, hooks, meta-query, sitemap

I'm trying to omit specific CPTs from the WordPress generated `wp-sitemap.xml` based on a meta key value. I only found one post online regarding this on [perishable press](https://perishablepress.com/customize-wordpress-sitemaps/#exclude-posts-meta), however it throws up a fatal error in PHP whether or not I modify it.

If anyone knows how to do this for meta key values or multiple meta key values using `relation`, I would appreciate some info. Last piece I need to finalize my sitemaps.

### Original code from Perishable Press (throws error)

```php
function shapeSpace_disable_sitemap_post_meta($args, $post_type) {
    
    if ('post' !== $post_type) return $args; // can be any post type
    
    $args['meta_query'] = isset($args['meta_query']) ? $args['meta_query'] : array();  
      
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        
        'key'     => 'sitemap', // can be any meta key
        'value'   => '1',       // can be any meta value
        'compare' => '=',       // can use any comparison
    );
    
    return $args;
    
}
add_filter('wp_sitemaps_posts_query_args', 'shapeSpace_disable_sitemap_post_meta');
```

### Modified Code (also throws error)

```php
function shapeSpace_disable_sitemap_post_meta($args, $post_type) {
    
    if ($post_type !== 'authors') return $args; // can be any post type
    
    $args['meta_query'] = isset($args['meta_query']) ? $args['meta_query'] : array();  
      
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        
            'key'     => 'doss_enabled', // can be any meta key
            'value'   => '1',       // can be any meta value
            'compare' => '=',       // can use any comparison
        );
    
    return $args;
    
}
add_filter('wp_sitemaps_posts_query_args', 'shapeSpace_disable_sitemap_post_meta');
```

### PHP Error Log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function shapeSpace_disable_sitemap_post_meta(), 1 passed in class-wp-hook.php on line 305 and exactly 2 expected in functions.php:92
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because the filter callback (`shapeSpace_disable_sitemap_post_meta()`) expects to receive two parameters (`$args` and `$post_type`) and yet you call [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) without setting the *fourth* parameter to `2`.

So to solve the problem:

```php
// Replace this:
add_filter('wp_sitemaps_posts_query_args', 'shapeSpace_disable_sitemap_post_meta');

// with this one:
add_filter('wp_sitemaps_posts_query_args', 'shapeSpace_disable_sitemap_post_meta', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot. I didn't know what the error was referring to. I'm still learning about filters. Much appreciated.